# Why will Foo::innerConstexpr not link, but UserLiteral{Foo::innerConstexpr} will?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Consider the following simple classes, which I've contrived based on issues I'm seeing with a real project.  Triple is a quick boiler-plate type for use with the inner `constexpr`s in class Foo:

```
#include <iostream>

class Triple {
public:
    friend
    std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & o, Triple const & t);

    constexpr Triple() : a_(0), b_(0), c_(0) { }
    constexpr Triple(Triple const & other) = default;
    constexpr Triple(double a, double b, double c)
      : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c)
    { }

    ~Triple() = default;

private:
    double a_, b_, c_;
};

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & o, Triple const & t) {
    o << "(" << t.a_ << ", " << t.b_ << ", " << t.c_ << ")";
    return o;
}

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : triple_(defaultTriple) { }

    Triple const & triple() const { return triple_; }
    Triple & triple() { return triple_; }

    constexpr static float defaultPOD{10};
    constexpr static Triple defaultTriple{11.0, 22.0, 33.0};

private:
    Triple triple_;
};
```

If I then write a `main()` function to use the public inner `constexpr`s from `Foo`, as follows, it will fail to link (using g++ 4.7.0, by way of mingw-x86-64 on Windows 7):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << Foo::defaultPOD << endl;
    cout << Foo::defaultTriple << endl;
}
```

```
    $ g++ -o test -O3 --std=c++11 test.cpp
    e:\temp\ccwJqI4p.o:test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x28): undefined reference to `Foo::defaultTriple' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if I write

```
cout << Triple{Foo::defaultTriple} << endl
```

instead of simply

```
cout << Foo::defaultTriple << endl
```

it will link and run fine.  I can see that the former expresses more explicitly that a compile-time literal is what's intended, but I'm still surprised the latter won't work as well.  Is this a compiler bug, or is there a reason based on the rules for `constexpr` that only the first example should work?

I would try other compilers to get more insight, but at present GCC 4.7.0 is the only one I have access to that supports `constexpr`.

Note also that the expression for the pod `constexpr` works fine without an explicit literal wrapper, e.g. `cout << Foo::defaultPOD` has never given me trouble.

Comment: To summarize what I gained from the responses, I solved the issue by providing _definitions_ (in addition to the `constexpr` _declarations_ inside `Foo`) outside of `Foo`, like so:  `constexpr Triple Foo::defaultTriple;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *constant expression* that appears in a context where a *constant expression* is not required may be evaluated during program translation but it is not required to be, so it might be evaluated at run time.

If a `constexpr` `static` member is evaluated during program translation the compiler can use its initializer to determine its value and won't need the member's definition.

If the member is used in a context that is evaluated at run time then its definition will be required.

In `cout << Foo::defaultTriple << endl` your compiler is generating the code to perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `Foo::defaultTriple` at run time so the object needs a definition.

In `cout << Triple{Foo::defaultTriple} << endl` the compiler is evaluating `Foo::defaultTriple` during program translation to create the temporary `Triple` that itself is probably evaluated at run time.

Unless your `constexpr` objects are only evaluated in contexts where *constant expressions* are required, you must provide a definition for them.

Comment: Thanks for the careful explanation.  I'm still puzzling over why `Foo::defaultTriple` and the result of translating `Triple{Foo::defaultValue}` would be evaluated at run-time.  Is this because of being passed to the overloaded `operator <<`?   Why is passing it by ref-to-a-const not enough to make it a constant expression?  And why, though I'm using it in exactly the same way, does Foo::defaultPOD _not_ need a similar definition?

Comment: Where you say, "Unless your constexpr objects are only evaluated in contexts where _constant expressions_ are required, you must provide a definition for them," does this entail that `cout << Foo::defaultTriple`... is a run-time evaluation context, and will thus require a definition, because I cannot mark the whole line with `constexpr`?  There must be something about the notion of a _constant expression_ that I'm missing here.

Comment: In the expression `cout << x`, `x` is in a context which doesn't _require_ a constant expression so it _may_ be evaluated only at run time. The same is true of any sub-expressions of `x` even if they are constant expressions. They are used, so must have definitions. If they are constant expressions the copmiler may be able to substitute them at translation time - in which case you might not get an error if you don't provide definitions - but you cannot rely on this.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean about `cout << x` being an expression that can also be evaluated at run-time.  Let me take a stab at re-phrasing it: Since 'x' could equally well be a run-time evaluated expression, this is not a context that _requires_ a constant expression, hence it is up to the compiler whether to do this at translation time or at run-time.  If it chooses the latter, the linker must be able to find a definition.  For correctness, portability, and a robust assurance that the program will link, I should always provide a definition.

Comment: I would thus hazard a guess that for Foo::defaultPOD, the compiler has been doing the computation at translation time, and this is why I haven't seen the linker error for that case.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultPOD` and `defaultTriple` declared inside the class is not a definition. You must define them outside of the class declaration if you want to use them in places that need to know their address.

So why does `cout << Foo::defaultPOD << endl;` work, but `cout << Foo::defaultTriple << endl;` doesn't?

`defaultPOD` is declared as a `float`, so when you do `cout << Foo::defaultPOD` it calls the `operator<<(float val);` which takes its argument *by value*. No definition is required in this call because you are only using the *value* (it's not odr-used as defined by 3.2.3). If you try to pass `Foo::defaultPOD` to a function that takes a reference, you would need to define it.

However, `Foo::defaultTriple` fails because `operator <<` takes a `Triple` by reference requiring `Foo::defaultTriple` to be defined. However, even after changing the `operator<<` to pass by value, in my tests, I still ended up with a linker error. Only if I remove the member variables from `Triple` and make `operator<<` pass by value will the code compile without defining the static member variables. (When you remove the member variables from `Triple` the compiler [optimizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) out the variable I believe).

(Here is a [nice reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition) which explains some of this stuff).

Comment: Hmm, if needing an address is the reason I'd need to define the static variables, it still seems curious that you have to remove all the non-static member values to not need a definition when passing by value.

Comment: @anthrond: Yes, actually I was thinking about reporting that as a bug (I'm also curious as to the specific rules). It may be the case that it is implementation dependent.

Comment: It looks to me like this lingering question may be covered by Charles Bailey's response and comments above--from those, I think it's reasonable to suppose that the discrepancy is an implementation artifact, so the safest thing is to always provide a definition.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the linker, it can not find the `Foo::defaultTriple` static member.

The issue here is the difference between "declaration" and "definition". The static line in your class is the declaration, you also need a definition. In C++, every `static` field defined inside a `class` should be also present inside a .cpp file:

```
// .hpp

class X {
    static int Q;
};

// .cpp

int X:Q = 0;
```

In your case, you should have this line somewhere in a .cpp file:

```
Triple foo::defaultTriple;
```

Comment: While, what you said above is true, the call `cout << Foo::defaultPOD << endl;` does not require a definition, but `cout << Foo::defaultTriple << endl;` does. Why is that?

Comment: I had experimented with various forms of out-of-class definitions, but I always tried it with an initialization value, and the compiler would complain about a previous declaration.  Thanks, though, cause your example finally led me to an out-of-class definition that worked, by adding 'constexpr' to the start of what you suggested: `constexpr Triple Foo::defaultTriple;`.  I'm still curious why these constraints don't apply to Foo::defaultPOD, however.